# Make custom system url

Tags: urls, plugins-url

Let's say my site is example.com
I want to create example.com/portfolio without creating a page.

I just want to execute some PHP code and display a bit of HTML.

Is there any way to create "sytem urls" (opposite to "content url") ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom page template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Random PHP
 */

get_header();
//add random PHP
get_sidebar();
get_footer(); 
?>
```

Create a page in WordPress, give it the title portfolio.  In the template select box choose Random PHP